# Pandas: how to convert a list into a matrix grouped by a column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe where the first column (CUSTOMER) is the name of the customer and the customer's name is repeated once for every product the customer has purchased (PRODUCT):

```
Customer  Product  Count
John      A        1
John      B        1
John      C        1
Mary      A        1
Mary      B        1
Charles   A        1
```

I want to pivot this data to create a new dataframe where both rows and columns are the category of product (PRODUCT) and the values are the count of the customer name, as follows:

```
Product
       A     B     C
A      0     2     1
B      2     0     1
C      1     1     0
```

So if John bought A and also bought B, +1 will be added to the A:B cell, he also bought A in combination with C, so there is a +1 on the A:C cell, and so on. Note that Charles does not appear in this dataframe because he only bought one product.

I tried to use pandas.pivot_table but this is what I got:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Product'], columns=['Product'], values=['Customer'])

>> KeyError: 'Level Product not found'
```

What method and parameters should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self `merge` with `crosstab`

```
d1 = df.merge(df, on='Customer').query('Product_x != Product_y')
pd.crosstab(d1.Product_x, d1.Product_y)

Product_y  A  B  C
Product_x         
A          0  2  1
B          2  0  1
C          1  1  0
```

---

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44379972/2336654) to get a better idea how to speed the `crosstab` up.  The key insight for this problem was the self merging.

Comment: You are right, merging the dataframe with itself with the merge() method and then transforming it into a matrix with crosstab() was a required step that I didn't know of. Thank you.